# How to capture single tap on gesture overlay view

Tags: android, gesture, gestures, android-gesture

I am working on app which is using gesture overlay view and it is really giving me the tough time. I a really getting it tough as it is hard to control, But Now I am at the point where I can not roll back to start.

So far I have three major problem among all others. these are as under.

1. First is how to detect the single tap on the gesture overlay view, it it get detected the swipe type gesture only. keep in mind I may require the tap gesture while setting the gesture overlay view  multiple gesture property. keep the example of word "i" letter where you want a vertical line and then the dot over it.
2. App gets crashed when I try to match the results of the gesture performed in the onGesturePerformed method . but it happens some times not all the time I performed the gesture.  I get the "Index out of bound the size is 2 and the index is 3" thsi error occurs , while it gives me no direction where it is happening. so I think its in the beneath part

   ```
      public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture)

       { 

   try {
       ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLibrary.recognize(gesture);
           if (!predictions.isEmpty()) {
           Prediction bestPrediction = predictions.get(0);
           double maxScore = predictions.get(0).score;
           for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
               if (prediction.score > maxScore) {
                   bestPrediction = prediction;
                   maxScore = prediction.score;
               }
           }
           if (bestPrediction.score > 18.00 && bestPrediction.name.equals("bay"))      {
         gOverlayBoard.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#98120b"));
               Intent intent = new Intent(System.this, Sounds.class);
               startActivity(intent);
          } else {
               clearBoard();
           }

           gOverlay.removeOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
       }
   } catch (RuntimeException e) {
       Log.d("MyGesture exception", e.getMessage());
   }}
   ```

I have tried catching the IndexOutOfBound Exception also ArrayOutOfBound exception but nothing is helping me and my app crashes in the same way. But it happens some time.

3. How to recognize the difference between the vertical line and the horizental line ?  If the gesture I made from the Gesture builder is vertical , its still can also be recognized in horizontal position . ? why where as I made the vertical gesture? and also how can I set the minimum length of gesture?

So please any one help me out in answering the confusion I shared above with a little example of code .